# MySQL is blocking (or how to optimize this)

Tags: mysql, optimization, ubuntu

I've a this query in mySQL (MyISAM):

```
SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `link` FROM `posts` WHERE `read_time`<'2010-10-16')
```

It seems ok for me, but MySQL hangs up with it.
'links' is a table with 16000 rows and 'posts' has arround 5000 rows.
'id' and 'link' are primary

I've made some tests:

1. Remove all records except a couple in each table. It works
2. Execute inner query (SELECT `link` FROM `posts` WHERE `read_time`<'2010-10-16') first and the execute the outer query (SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `id` IN ('1232','1354','3324')). It works
3. Try to upgrade my Ubuntu, but it says that this is the last mySQL version (5.1.37-1ubuntu5.5)

What's happening? I've found a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No, this is not a bug. As Mark Byers mentioned, a `JOIN` will work quiet better. `IN` will compare everything against everything if I remember right, and so end up with 16k*5k comparisons.

Comment: post you explain plan the answer will then be self evident - use a join + index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL currently isn't so good at optimizing statements of this form:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE x IN (subquery)
```

This is in [MySQL's bug database](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32665) and it should be fixed in MySQL 5.6 and MySQL 6.0.
To solve your issue you can use a JOIN instead of `IN`:

```
SELECT links.*
FROM links
JOIN posts ON links.id = posts.link
WHERE posts.read_time < '2010-10-16'
```

You should also try adding an index on `read_time` if you don't already have one.

Comment: Actually as far as I know it's been fixed in 5.4. Will check today after I install 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

As Mark Byers suggests, use a JOIN. [This is a very accessible introduction to JOINs](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). You can also consult [MySQL's documentation on the JOIN operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mark Byers, if possible use timestamp instead of datetime on 'read_time' if you don't already do this.